# Looking for a way to convert ieee754 hex from a csv file into decimal values for a webpage

Tags: php, csv, ieee-754

title pretty much says it all. I've got a stats plugin that outputs in 64-bit ieee754 format inside a .csv file. I need some method of pulling the columns, determining if the row is a long integer already or if it's a double precision hex value. For the ones that are hex, they need to be converted into decimal format and the long integers can be left alone.

My csv file has just 3 columns, the first being playername, the second is either "long" or "double" and the third is either the long integer or a hex value.

I just need to take this as an array and display it on a page with the hex converted into decimals. Can anyone help with this?

Here's my code so far:

```
$file_handle = fopen("variables.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";
}

fclose($file_handle);
```

`$line_of_text[2]` is what needs to be converted in each row.

http://l4dpromod.com/variables.txt is an example of what I have to be converted. (csv renamed to txt so you can read it)

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to give us a starting point, also known as.. what you've already tried.

Comment: Well I don't know much about programming, was really hoping that I could find a couple conversion scripts and throw them together to accomplish what I needed. Turns out that I can't find a working php function anywhere. I was able to find something that printed out my csv as an array though, so really I just need something to convert the hex values into decimals.

Comment: the code i have so far is: 

`<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("variables.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

print $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . "<BR>";

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>`

Comment: Code does little help in a comment.  Use the edit link.